# Query to select max value of a column using max using cassandra

Tags: cassandra

We have table called table1 with Tableindex as column. we need the maximum value of tableindex which must result as 3. Consider this table as example(table1),

```
     Tableindex Creationdate                Documentname    Documentid 
         1      2017-01-18 11:59:06+0530    Document 1      Doc_1
         2      2017-01-18 12:09:06+0530    Document 2      Doc_2
         3      2017-01-18 01:09:06+0530    Document 3      Doc_3
```

In sql, we can select the max value using the following query,
           "**Select max(Tableindex) from table1;**"  // result in 3.

Similarly how can we get the max value in **cassandra query.** Is there Max function in cassandra. If not how can we get the max value?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create user defined aggregate functions in cassandra 2.2 and above.

Comment: I am using cassandra of version 2.0.

Answer (score 8):

In Cassandra 2.2, the standard aggregate functions of min, max, avg, sum, and count are built-in functions.

```
SELECT MAX(column_name) FROM keyspace.table_name ;
```

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useQueryStdAggregate.html

Answer (score 2):

If you do select  * from table1 limit 1, the result will give you row with MAX  Tableindex .

There are better ways to do this with cassandra. you shoud know few things while designing cassandra tables.

1- Design your table for your queries.

2- Design to distributed data across the cassandra cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade to Cassandra higher version (2.2+) , it has built in max func.